# Why running a programme on a Bash conveyor after gcc shoots its performance up?

Tags: c, linux, performance, gcc

I would like to learn the causes of the pecularities with performance, just take a look at the output of the following programme:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#define ARR1_LEN 16384

#define PRINT_DUR {\
    printf("%ld - %ld = %ld\n%.20Lf\n", t2, t1, t2-t1, ((long double)(t2 - t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);\
}

int main() {
    int *arr1_ = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARR1_LEN + 64);
    int temp;
    if (!arr1_) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int *arr1 = (int*)((((size_t)arr1_)+63)&0xffffffffffffffc0);
    clock_t t1, t2;

    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < (ARR1_LEN>>6); i++) {
        temp = arr1[i<<6];
    }
    t2 = clock();

    PRINT_DUR

    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < (ARR1_LEN>>6); i++) {
        temp = arr1[(i<<6) + 32];
    }
    t2 = clock();

    PRINT_DUR

    free(arr1_);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ g++ ./dump.cpp -g -o ./dump && ./dump 
403 - 391 = 12
0.00001200000000000000
429 - 428 = 1
0.00000100000000000000
$ ./dump 
1707 - 1650 = 57
0.00005700000000000000
1802 - 1798 = 4
0.00000400000000000000
```

As you can see from the statistics above, the programme runned just after `g++` works 4 times faster. I wonder why.

P.S. It was cut for one sample for the post. Actually, I have tested it many times an it differs quite rarely.

**UPDATE**:

```
$ g++ ./dump.cpp -g -o ./dump && ./dump 
402 - 390 = 12
0.00001200000000000000
426 - 425 = 1
0.00000100000000000000
$ ./dump && ./dump && ./dump && ./dump 
1723 - 1665 = 58
0.00005800000000000000
1858 - 1852 = 6
0.00000600000000000000
1650 - 1593 = 57
0.00005700000000000000
1783 - 1777 = 6
0.00000600000000000000
1733 - 1676 = 57
0.00005700000000000000
1812 - 1807 = 5
0.00000500000000000000
1607 - 1550 = 57
0.00005700000000000000
1714 - 1708 = 6
0.00000600000000000000
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$ for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do VAR=$((i*i)); done ; ./dump 
405 - 393 = 12
0.00001200000000000000
428 - 427 = 1
0.00000100000000000000
```

Comment: These are really small performance numbers that mean very little. Try making a loop that takes time in the order of seconds to get any reasonable benchmark.

Comment: @Kostas: I simplified my programme to show. And I have taken statistics on more than one shot. Actually it was a programme for another sake, I just faced with this permanent correlation, amazed and wondered.

Comment: The question seems to be a C question rather than a C++ question! I do realize that the C code is thinly veiled as C++ code using the C++ headers but everything about the actual code is just C.

Comment: what do you get for `./dump && ./dump`?  is the 2nd one faster?

Comment: @markp-fuse: updated the question

Comment: Many computers have dynamic CPU clock speed adjustment.  If the machine has been idle for a while, the CPU is throttled down to save energy, and doesn't increase to full speed until it has been under load for some time.

Comment: testing unoptimized code is pointless. And with optimization a big part of your code is eliminated

Answer (score 0):

Because your OS is **allocating CPU time** (CPU priority) to compilation which is time consuming.

Just run it multiple times and you will get approx. the same result.

```
./dump && ./dump && ./dump && ./dump
```

Your program is not an accurate benchmark because it is very light in terms of CPU use, so the OS is pretty flexible in terms of priority.

Comment: no, it does not work this way. And take a note that time is **less** with compilation than without. The topic is updated.

Comment: It is precisely how it works. And that is exactly what I said. You are not accounting for compilation time in your benchmark obviously because it happens **before** execution.

Comment: You need to run it a thousand+ times. Like I said, your code is light. If your terminal is zsh run this: for ((i=0;i<1500;i+=1)); do ./dump; done

Comment: take a note that this programme measures time within its run time, i.e. it must have been compiled already before being able to make a syscall for getting time. On top of that `&&` means running programme `after` compilation. What connection is between them?

Comment: running `for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do ./dump; done` changes nothing